# MSBuild echo task?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a task in MSBuild that's synonymous with NAnt's [`<echo>` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/echo.html)?

I don't want anything fancy, just a simple message output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

MsBuild has the [Message task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/message-task) built in which will output a string to the console:

```xml
<Target ...>
  <Message Text="text to output" />
</Target>
```

By default, MSBuild logs at `minimal` verbosity which will prevent these messages from being seen. Either increase the verbosity, or set the `Message`'s `Importance` parameter to `high`:

```xml
<Target ...>
  <Message Text="text to output ALWAYS" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Useful, but unfortunately the Message task only works inside a Target, you can't just sprinkle your build script with messages.